# React version of React Native Elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm used to writing React Native code, but I'm currently working on a React App, so I was wondering is there is something like React Native Elements but for React as such.

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are many UI component libraries suitable for React App development. A few that come to mind are:

- ### Material-UI

  React components that implement Google's Material Design.

  https://material-ui.com/
- ### React-Bootstrap

  The most popular front-end framework, rebuilt for React.

  https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US
- ### Element-React

  Element was initially written in Vue, which has many elegant UI components, but we also love React, so we forked it for the React community.

  https://github.com/elemefe/element-react